# Animated barplot via gganimate: conflict of view_follow & coord_flip

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, axis-labels, gganimate

I want to crate an animated barchart with the `gganim` package. The coordinates of the barchart should be flipped via `coord_flip` (i.e. horizontal bars) and the x-axis should be made flexible depending on the length of the bars via `view_follow`.

Consider the following example data:

```
# Create example data
df <- data.frame(ordering = c(rep(1:3, 2), 3:1, rep(1:3, 2)),
                 year = factor(sort(rep(2001:2005, 3))),
                 value = round(runif(15, 0, 100)),
                 group = rep(letters[1:3], 5))
```

If I create an animated barchart without `coord_flip`, everything works fine:

```
library("gganimate")
library("ggplot2")

# Create animated ggplot without coord_flip
ggp <- ggplot(df, aes(x = ordering, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = group)) +
  transition_states(year, transition_length = 2, state_length = 0) +
  view_follow(fixed_x = TRUE) # +
  # coord_flip()
ggp
```

[image]

However, if I add `coord_flip`, the axes are moving from side to side without any reason:

```
# Create animated ggplot with coord_flip
ggp2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = ordering, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = group)) +
  transition_states(year, transition_length = 2, state_length = 0) +
  view_follow(fixed_x = TRUE) +
  coord_flip()
ggp2
```

[image]

**Question: How could I flip the axis of my barchart AND enable a flexible axis?**

Comment: bug report https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/336

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to consider `geom_barh` from the ggstance package, instead of `geom_bar` + `coord_flip`:

```
library(ggstance)

ggplot(df, aes(y = ordering, x = value)) +
  geom_barh(stat = "identity", aes(fill = group)) +
  transition_states(year, transition_length = 2, state_length = 0) +
  view_follow(fixed_y = TRUE)
```

[image: animated plot]